# Inserting view into table - view doesn't take long to run - Insert takes forever

Tags: sql, performance, view, insert

I have a view which takes roughly 1 second to return 1000 rows.
However when I try to INSERT this into a table it takes a long time (even just 1000 rows).

The view itself in FULL returns around 600,000,000 rows. Due to limitations on my machine I can only display 1000 at a time. When I limit the view to 1000 rows it takes 1 second to run. When I try to insert these 1000 rows it takes minutes! 
I've also tried to insert all 600 Million rows and this never finishes - 2 hours in it times out.

```
   SELECT *
   FROM vw_view1
   LIMIT 1000
```

The above takes 1 second to run

```
   insert into table1

    SELECT *
    FROM vw_view1
    LIMIT 1000
     ;
```

The above takes 5 minutes!

Is there a reason why simply querying the view would take second and the insert takes 5 minutes? Remember this is just for 1000 rows! I need to actually insert 600,000,000!

Here is the query of my view

**I have excluded field names and table names for confidentiality purposes**

```
  SELECT id, sheet, "timestamp", "timestamp"::date AS date,
  "date_part"('year'::text, "timestamp") AS year, "date_part"('month'::text, "timestamp") AS month, user_id, 
    CASE
          WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        ELSE 'Free'::text
    END AS column1, 
    CASE
         WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        ELSE 'Homel'::text
    END AS column2, 
    CASE
       WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        ELSE 'include'
    END AS column3, 
    CASE
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        WHEN XX like %...%.... THEN ...ZZ
        ELSE 'ignore'

    END AS column4
    FROM views;
```

So to run the above query for 1000 rows takes 1 second. To insert that query into an empty tables takes 5 minutes.

To run the above query for ALL rows never finishes! TO insert that query into an empty tables never finishes.

I have two issues effectively.

1. Why does it take so much longer to insert a simple select into an empty table
2. How do I optimise the query above

I am using amazon redshift

Thank you in advance

Comment: You are asking why inserting/selecting 1000 rows is faster than inserting/selecting 600,000,000 rows?

Comment: Could be lots of things.  Rewriting indexes and foreign key checking come to mind.

Comment: Do you have triggers on the empty table? Can you show the sql insert code?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question,a database is a structured storage of data so that people can easily access data that is accurate and consistent.  Writing to a database is always going to be slower than reading a database.  INSERT would always take longer than SELECT.  Sometimes order of magnitude longer.

It depends on your system why it takes 5 minutes to insert 1000 rows.  With a modern database, it usually does not take so long.  However, it can easily take so much time if you are using a low-tier database from amazon redshift, and/or if your view tables have a lot of columns with complexity.

For your second question, without proper context, it's hard to say.  However, if your SELECT query is only taking 1 second, my guess is the database can figure out the data set you want to write fairly fast.  My guess is there is something going on with the writing speed of the database.  Maybe you are using a low tier service that has low max speed on write performance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand what is going on with your database design to understand why this is slow.  You need to look at foreign keys, at the hardware you are running, whether there are implicit conversions happening, whether there are triggers.

You need to see what fields it is indexing at the time of insert. You need to look at whether more indexes on the underlying tables are needed for the select query for the insert to run faster.

Of course all of those case statements are going to make it slow all by themselves. Can they be replaced with something faster but more complicated looking like a series of UNION (or preferably UNION ALL) statements?

It could also be a network pipeline issue. Sometimes things are better run directly on the database than from some other location.

Next you virtually never want to insert  600,000,000 in one go. It is often faster to do it in batches and commit the batches before going to the next. This is because otherwise the transaction log fills up and that can be part of the slowness.

There are very large books on performance tuning, you need to read them for your chosen database. This type of thing is never simple. Nor can it properly be addressed in a place like this. This is something that **you personally** need to develop in depth knowledge of before you can even start to fix this.  This is why database specialists are necessary for any complex, large database system. If you have this many records in one view in your database and no database specialists to help you with this, then you need to hire one since you do not have the requisite 10,000 hours of specialized knowledge and experience to be able to do this effectively.